# Android Studio - Converting Website to Android App Update Issue

Tags: android

If I use Android Studio to convert a website into an app, will the Android app update automatically with new content or changes you make on the website? Or, will I have to add some new code? If so, can someone lead me in the direction of a good tutorial concerning the matter.

Answer (score 1):

It all depends of your technique of conversion. If you are about to use WebView just to display already finished mobile version of your site, then yes, your content will be updated as soon as you update your website. However, if you are about to hard-code some stuff (let's say for example: menu categories), then the answer is no, you have to update your application. If you want to avoid that, you need to start using some kind of comunication between your website and application (usually REST JSON). If you set it right, then all should work flawlessly.